# htaccess on Nginx website sub folder not work

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

PLease help. i have a website with url domain.com/login.php and after user login they will automaticly redirrect into domain/Users/Dashboard
and the problem is .htaccess location is in the Users folder.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^modal/$  modal.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/$  dashboard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^help/$  help.php [L]                          
RewriteRule ^add_email/$  add_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_email/$  view_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_email/$  edit_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^send_email/$  send_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_sends_email/$  view_sends_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^validate_email/$  validate_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^validate_number/$  validate_number.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_sms/$  add_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_sms/$  view_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_sms/$  edit_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^send_sms/$  send_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_sends_sms/$  view_sends_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_llamadas/$  add_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^send_llamadas/$  send_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_llamadas/$  view_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_sends_llamadas/$  view_sends_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_llamadas/$  edit_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_historial/$  view_historial.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_historial_email/$  view_historial_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_historial_sms/$  view_historial_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_historial_llamadas/$  view_historial_llamadas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_process/$  view_process.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_whatsapp/$  add_whatsapp.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^fmi_opent2/$  fmi_opent2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmi_openraw/$  fmi_openraw.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmi_openm/$  fmi_openm.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmi_token/$  fmi_token.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tools/$  tools.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ip_address/$  ip_address.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bypass/$  bypass.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmiwin/$  fmiwin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmimac/$  fmimac.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmiwin_decode/$  fmiwin_decode.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmimac_decode/$  fmimac_decode.php [L]
RewriteRule ^pagos/$  pagos.php [L]

RewriteRule ^buy_service/$  buy_service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fmi_check/$  fmi_check.php [L]
RewriteRule ^my_service/$  my_service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^success_data/$  success_data.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_template/$  add_template.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/$  settings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users_admin/$  users_admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_users/$  add_users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_user/$  edit_users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_money/$  add_money.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings_email/$  settings_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^templates_email/$  templates_email.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings_sms/$  settings_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^templates_sms/$  templates_sms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domains/$  domains.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_service/$  add_service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_orders/$  view_orders.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_orders/$  edit_orders.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit_service/$  edit_service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^instant_service/$  instant_service.php [L]
RewriteRule ^add_iking/$  add_iking.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings_server/$  settings_server.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings_notify/$  settings_notify.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings_help/$  settings_help.php [L]
RewriteRule ^generator_demo/$  generator_demo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^autoremove/$  autoremove.php [L]
RewriteRule ^qrcode/$  qrcode.php [L]

RewriteRule ^action/$  php/system.php [L]
```

and  i have convert it into nginx with result:

```
autoindex off;

location = /modal {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /modal.php break;
}

location = /dashboard {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /dashboard.php break;
}

location = /help {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /help.php break;
}

location = /add_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_email.php break;
}

location = /view_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_email.php break;
}

location = /edit_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_email.php break;
}

location = /send_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /send_email.php break;
}

location = /view_sends_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_sends_email.php break;
}

location = /validate_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /validate_email.php break;
}

location = /validate_number {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /validate_number.php break;
}

location = /add_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_sms.php break;
}

location = /view_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_sms.php break;
}

location = /edit_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_sms.php break;
}

location = /send_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /send_sms.php break;
}

location = /view_sends_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_sends_sms.php break;
}

location = /add_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /send_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /send_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /view_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /view_sends_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_sends_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /edit_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /view_historial {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_historial.php break;
}

location = /view_historial_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_historial_email.php break;
}

location = /view_historial_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_historial_sms.php break;
}

location = /view_historial_llamadas {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_historial_llamadas.php break;
}

location = /view_process {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_process.php break;
}

location = /add_whatsapp {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_whatsapp.php break;
}

location = /fmi_opent2 {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmi_opent2.php break;
}

location = /fmi_openraw {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmi_openraw.php break;
}

location = /fmi_openm {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmi_openm.php break;
}

location = /fmi_token {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmi_token.php break;
}

location = /tools {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /tools.php break;
}

location = /ip_address {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /ip_address.php break;
}

location = /bypass {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /bypass.php break;
}

location = /fmiwin {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmiwin.php break;
}

location = /fmimac {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmimac.php break;
}

location = /fmiwin_decode {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmiwin_decode.php break;
}

location = /fmimac_decode {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmimac_decode.php break;
}

location = /pagos {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /pagos.php break;
}

location = /buy_service {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /buy_service.php break;
}

location = /fmi_check {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /fmi_check.php break;
}

location = /my_service {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /my_service.php break;
}

location = /success_data {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /success_data.php break;
}

location = /add_template {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_template.php break;
}

location = /settings {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings.php break;
}

location = /users_admin {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /users_admin.php break;
}

location = /add_users {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_users.php break;
}

location = /edit_user {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_users.php break;
}

location = /add_money {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_money.php break;
}

location = /settings_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings_email.php break;
}

location = /templates_email {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /templates_email.php break;
}

location = /settings_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings_sms.php break;
}

location = /templates_sms {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /templates_sms.php break;
}

location = /domains {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /domains.php break;
}

location = /add_service {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_service.php break;
}

location = /view_orders {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /view_orders.php break;
}

location = /edit_orders {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_orders.php break;
}

location = /edit_service {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /edit_service.php break;
}

location = /instant_service {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /instant_service.php break;
}

location = /add_iking {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /add_iking.php break;
}

location = /settings_server {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings_server.php break;
}

location = /settings_notify {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings_notify.php break;
}

location = /settings_help {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /settings_help.php break;
}

location = /generator_demo {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /generator_demo.php break;
}

location = /autoremove {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /autoremove.php break;
}

location = /qrcode {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /qrcode.php break;
}

location = /action {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /php/system.php break;
}
```

but after trying i still got 404 not found. how to fix this htaccess located not in the public_html or root folder from domain?

I have convert and still not work